# Toggle css in react component is not applied

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following component which map over an array and display a set of buttons which they render specific content:

```js
export const Bookings = ({bookings}) => {
    const [selectedBooking, setSelectedBooking] = useState(false);
    const handleSelectedBooking = (id, destination) => {}
    const handleToggleButton = () => {
        setSelectedBooking(!selectedBooking)
    }
    
    return(
       <div>
        {
          bookings.map(booking => (
            <button
              className={selectedBooking ? 'selectedBooking' : 'notSelectedBooking'}
              onClick={() => {
                handleSelectedBooking(booking.id, booking.destination)
                handleToggleButton()
              }}
            >
              {booking.destination}
            </button>
          ))
        }
       </div>
    )
}
```

Where I have these styles already defined but somehow the styles are not applied, did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your ternary operator. It should be selectedBooking instead of selectedBoking.

Comment: it is not the issue, it was a typo but I have fixed it, your answer didn;t fix the problem :

Comment: If you inspect the element using your browser's developer tools, is the class name applied but the styles in the class are empty, or is the class name not applied at all?

Answer (score 0):

Did you import styles file in the current file, where you write your component?

Moreover, I recommend you using modules to set styles in your component. How this works: you name your css file like this MyStyles.module.css (.module is obligatory) and then import in React component file these styles like `import styles from './MyStyles.module.css'`. Then you set styles in jsx code like this: `className={selectedBoking ? styles.selectedBooking : styles.notSelectedBooking}`.

This approach makes classnames unique across all the project even though they have the same names in different css files.

Comment: yes I have configured my react app to use hashed css classes but the issue is not there actually and of course I'm importing the css/scss file and I was using it as import styles from './Component.scss'

Comment: If you use hashed classes you should name your styles file Components.module.scss and import it as `import styles from './Component.module.scss'`